# Comma after full date?

Tags: punctuation

Is it okay to delete the comma after '1969' below ?

Joe said, "February 7, 1969[,]is my date of birth."

And can we delete the comma after 'Indiana' and '2015' below?

Lisa reported, "The Gary, Indiana[,] man was arrested on charges of conspiracy."

Johnson said, "The February 1, 2015[,] meeting has been canceled."

After all, '1969', 'Indiana' and '2015' are all essential information and are *not* parenthetical elements; hence those commas should be removed, right?

Thank you.

Comment: None of those sentences need commas anyway. They're not optional in those cases, they're wrong.

Comment: the first one can avoided by saying _"My date of birth is February 7, 1969"_

Comment: But we'd need one after *Indiana* in the following sentence: Mike said, "Gary, Indiana, is my home town." If we omitted the comma after *Indiana* in that sentence it'd look as though we were telling Gary that *Indiana* is my home town. Thus we should retain the comma in this one, correct?

Comment: mplungjan, this is a direct quote that cannot be recast. Comma or no comma, then?

Comment: James Webster, when you said none of those sentences needed commas, did you mean after the dialog tags as well?

Comment: @whippoorwill, I was exclusively looking *inside* the quotation marks.

Comment: @James Webster I've seen a strong argument based on traditional rules that the second comma in "The Gary, Indiana, man was arrested on charges of conspiracy." is quite acceptable (see the thread I mention; see Jon Hanna's mention of parentheticals ). What justification do you have to say it _is_ wrong? (Please don't just cite a style guide advising this particular style.)

Comment: `See the thread I mention`, I'd like to read this. Where do you mention it please?

Comment: @James Webster So how about correcting / deleting your erroneous claim above. Which persists in your _answer_: 'They're not optional in those cases, they're wrong.'

Comment: Forgot that I ever asked this. Must be getting senile.

Answer (score 1):

None of those sentences need commas anyway. They're not optional in those cases, they're wrong.

However it's fine to have a comma after a date.

e.g.

> After the meeting on 1 February, 2014, two decisions were made about the university's new prospectus.

And it's fine to have them after your [toponym](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/toponym), just not in that sentence.

> First, the prospectus would picture Gary, Indiana, the destination of the new campus.

---

The commas *in the middle* of those examples are just part of the layout of the constructs. Don't treat those like "normal", clause separating commas.

```
1 February, 2014  
          ^
Gary, Indiana
    ^
```

---

Looking at an example from your comments, this one is a little more fuzzy:

The confusion arises because "Gary" is also a person's name. But would you put a comma there if the toponym wasn't a given name?

> Mike said, "Gary, Indiana, is my home town."
>   I said, "South Shields, England is my home town."

In this case I would say the comma is optional.

Comment: In summation, all four examples are punctuated below *exactly* as presented, correct (yes or no)?

Joe said, "February 7, 1969 is my date of birth." (No comma after "1969" here?)

Lisa reported, "The Gary, Indiana man was arrested on charges of conspiracy." (No comma after "Indiana" here?)

Johnson said, "The February 1, 2015 meeting has been canceled."
(No comma after "2015" here?)

Mike said, "Gary, Indiana, is my home town." (Comma required after "Indiana" in this one?)

Comment: The first three are correct now.

Comment: The last one, I'd say the comma is optional.

Comment: James, how could the comma in the last sentence be optional? We need a comma after *Indiana* in the following sentence: Mike said, "Gary, Indiana, is my home town." If we omitted the comma after *Indiana* in that sentence it'd look as though we were telling Gary that Indiana is my home town. Thus we should retain the comma in this one, correct? The inclusion or omission of the comma after *Indiana* drastically changes the complexion -- and meaning -- of the sentence here, no?

Comment: If you ignore the fact that in this specific example, the place name happens to be a given name, the pattern is `<place-name><optional-comma> is my home town.`

Comment: It doesn't change the meaning to omit or retain the comma, but it might require a little awareness on the part of your readers to either know or realise that "Gary, Indiana" is a place if it's omitted.

Comment: So the it would be senseless to say that the pattern follows an inviolable rule. You can't just ignore awkward cases.

Comment: ergo, "optional"

Comment: It certainly *does* alter the meaning. I cannot believe that you don't see this.

Comment: James, "Gary, Indiana is my hometown." (= I'm informing Gary that Indiana is my home town) versus "Gary, Indiana, is my home town (= 'Gary, Indiana' is in fact my home town. I'm not addressing anybody here.)

Comment: It doesn't alter the meaning. It may/could/would make it ambiguous, especially if the audience is unaware of A Town Like Gary. There's no reason to separate the subject "Gary, Indiana" from its verb; and one could say that if there's a comma after *Indiana* then that word is a parenthetical phrase (so both are correct).

Comment: Thank you Andrew. You've explained what I wanted to say more clearly than I could manage this morning.